# Calcul len for each row in column and take only one who respect the condition Pandas Python

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe, delete-row

num_excel_file_3 ( here I have My matrice (Dataframe) index,row,column)

with Dataframe I Have:

[image]

Now I want to update all Dataframe with condition :

`if len for each row in 'CLIENT NUM' < 6`            I will keep this line

in this column I have string and number so what I do :

`num_excel_file_3['CLIENT NUM'] = num_excel_file_3['CLIENT NUM'].astype(str)`

Now I have string for each row -> :)

next step find the way `len(num_excel_file_3['CLIENT NUM'].values < 6`

for example :

`dfini = num_excel_file_3[num_excel_file_3['CLIENT NUM'] !='10790']` work I delet the line where I have string(10790)

But what about `len(......) <6` ?

Thank you guys

Comment: kindly share data, not pics. with expected output

Comment: sammywemmy how I can exclude nan ?

Comment: ```dropna()``` possibly?

Comment: dfini=num_excel_file_3[num_excel_file_3['CLIENT NUM'] != 'nan']

Comment: dropna(dfini)  ?

Comment: If I want delet all letter and have only number : like 1413PO =1413 , How I can do ?

Comment: u r having multiple questions in one. besides, if u search on google, i believe it will link u to solutions on stackoverflow for this. i'd like to believe there are similar questions to this.

Answer (score 0):

I find the way !!! I try during 3 hours but want to find easy way so I post here. After posted I find the answer !!

```
dfini=num_excel_file_3[num_excel_file_3['CLIENT NUM'].map(len) < 6]

print(dfini)
```

[image]

Comment: dfini=dfini[dfini['CLIENT NUM'] != 'nan']